# Is there an easy way to convert an Objective-C 2.0 file to Objective-C 1?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there an easy way to convert an Objective-C 2.0 file to Objective-C 1? I am writing a Cocoa app, and I decided to support Tiger, which doesn't support Obj. C 2.0. I know I should have thought of it before I wrote a whole bunch of code, but is there an easy way to convert it back? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [Objective-C 1.0 `foreach` macro](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2006/07/15/cocoa-foreach-macro/) that can make converting the `for(id obj in collection)` loops a lot easier. Using it, you can say: `foreach(id,obj,collection){…}`. I used it for a couple of years before fast enumeration, and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

- If you are using Garbage Collection, you'll need to undo that.
- Remove all property usage (writing your own accessors where needed)
- If you are iterating through collections via `for(object in collection)` you'll need to redo.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using GC, so that's taken care of. I use plenty of properties, though. Is there a script or tool that will let me convert it?

Comment: I would search through Xcode plugins. But I have a feeling this is not a popular request. I've seen somethings that create properties, but not any that remove them.

Comment: Write yourself a script, it's quite simple.